# Visual Studio 2017 TypeScript fails to save

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-2017

I have never used TypeScript before and so perhaps I am misunderstanding how to use it. I right click and say new create a xxx.ts file, I write some code in it and click save. Clicking save tries to make the new file dialog pop up, and it says that there is already a TypeScript file present, I close the dialog and try again and VS 2017 crashes. I am sorry for the brief amount of information. However it is as simple as that, I create a new ts file write some code attempt to save and it thinks I created a new file.

Also I notice that after a fresh boot of VS I can save my typescript files, although after about a few minutes this create a new file behavior starts.

Another odd problem is opening a folder with the file explorer that has a .ts file in I cannot right click the .ts file. Doing so crashes Windows explorer.

I am a clean install of Windows 10, just did a reset. Only installed VS 2017 and SQL Server 2016.

Something visual:
[image: Trying to save app.module.ts]

Comment: Hi Bailey, can you tell me what kind of project you are in? Is your source code sharable? I am having a hard time reproducing this.

Comment: I have learned that it was a Windows Security update. I need to find the number of the update and share that in this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** Instead of removing the KB mentioned below, install this one which fixes the bug introduced by KB4013429: http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4015438

---

I have the same problem with Intellij Idea. I suspect that https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4013429/windows-10-update-kb4013429  could have something in common. There is known issue '*Windows DVD Player (and 3rd party apps that use Microsoft MPEG-2 libraries) crashes when run*' and '*.ts' files are also '*compresses video data using standard MEPG-2 (.MPEG) video compression*'.

Removing this update (kb4013429) helps a little.

Comment: This is what I believe to be the correct answer. I found this link probably a day or so after posting this question and tested and it worked. Then deleted my history and couldn't find it again to post here as answer, thank you.

Comment: This KB is supposed to fix the DVD Player bug, so may fix the general issue w/TS files. At least now I can right-click TS files. Will see if VS stops acting up now. http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4015438

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: make sure those typescript files are not indexed.

One way (this is how on Windows 10)

1. In File Explorer,
2. Right click the folder that contains the
   TypeScript files.
3. Go to Properties,
4. On the General tab,
5. Click Advanced,
6. Deselect "Allow files in this folder to have contents indexed in addition to file properties."

   I found the general idea by

   1. Clicking on VS 2017 Help, and
   2. Going to Send Feedback, then
   3. Report a Problem, and then
   4. searching for my issue. (in this case I searched for: typescript

This gets you past this bug until they fix it.

Comment: Are there any disadvantages to this fix? Is it just that the files may not appear in a windows search?

Comment: @berkeleybross, I haven't heard of, any nor run into, any evidence of any disadvantages.

Answer (score 0):

> Also I notice that after a fresh boot of VS I can save my typescript files, although after about a few minutes this create a new file behavior starts.

Follow the report a problem workflow for Visual Studio: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio-2017

Your useage of TypeScript is correct. Visual studio (at least your installation) seems to have a bug.

Comment: I did report my problem in this manner. I am also having a problem that I cannot right click a .ts file in my file explorer.

Comment: Recommend giving VSCode a go 

Comment: But I want the full power of Visual Studio

Comment: I did some Googling and apparently a Windows update was causing the problem Uninstalling seems to have fixed my issue with not being able to right click .ts files.